# Design issue with Stacklayout alignment

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to have a listview with switch control in my xamarin.forms app. I have used a stacklayout to align my content of the listview. I want a image, 2 labels and a switch control to display on each of the list item. I am unable to get it all aligned in the way i want it to.

I have attached 4 images. Image 1 shows the desired design and image 2 is the output on Android, an image 3 is output on windows device of what I get and image 4 is the folder structure.  [image: Desired Design] [image: Output on Android Device][image: Output on Windows][image]

Here is the stacklayout structure I am using. I have also tried it with RelativeLayout but doesn't seem to work either.

```
Label name = new Label();
name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Name"));
name.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
name.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

Label date = new Label();
date.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Date"));
date.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
date.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

Image img = new Image();
img.Source = Device.OnPlatform(
iOS: ImageSource.FromFile("Images/img.png"),
Android: ImageSource.FromFile("Images/img.png"),
WinPhone: ImageSource.FromFile("Images/img.png"));

img.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
img.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

Switch mainSwitch = new Switch();
mainSwitch.SetBinding(Switch.IsToggledProperty, new Binding("IsSelected"));
mainSwitch.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;

/*RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout();
layout.Children.Add(img,
    Constraint.Constant(5),
    Constraint.Constant(5),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Width - 60),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Height - 10)
);
layout.Children.Add(name,
    Constraint.Constant(5),
    Constraint.Constant(5),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Width - 60),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Height - 10)
);
layout.Children.Add(date,
    Constraint.Constant(5),
    Constraint.Constant(25),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Width - 60),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Height - 10)
);
layout.Children.Add(mainSwitch,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Width - 55),
    Constraint.Constant(5),
    Constraint.Constant(50),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Height - 10)
);*/
/*View = layout;*/

View = new StackLayout
{
    Children = {
        img,
        name,
        mainSwitch,
        date

    }
};
```

Also the issue here is I cannot get my image to show up on any of the device. Any help with design issue and showing up the image will be helpful.

**Edit**
I would like to know how to make this listview responsive? Right now the listview seems to become tiny on a 10" screen. How do I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the layout for the `ViewCell` use something like the following (I have left out any bindings):-

```
        Grid objGrid = new Grid();
        objGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
        //
        objGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
        {
          Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        });
        //
        objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(75, GridUnitType.Absolute)
        });
        objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        });
        objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = GridLength.Auto
        });

        //
        // Column 1:-
        Image objImage = new Image();
        objImage.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        objImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("Image1.png");
        objGrid.Children.Add(objImage, 0,0);

        //
        // Column 2:-
        StackLayout objStackLayoutCol2 = new StackLayout();            
        objGrid.Children.Add(objStackLayoutCol2, 1,0);

        Label objLabel1 = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Name"
        };
        Label objLabel2 = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Date"
        };
        objStackLayoutCol2.Children.Add(objLabel1);
        objStackLayoutCol2.Children.Add(objLabel2);

        //
        // Column 3:-
        Switch objSwitch = new Switch();
        objGrid.Children.Add(objSwitch, 2,0);
```

For image file placement refer to [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) that will be useful.

i.e. on `Android`, you will need to ensure the image is an `AndroidResource` and is placed in the `Drawable's` section in `Resources`.

**Update 1:-**

For `WindowsPhone` make sure the image is specified as `Build Action` of `Content` and put the image in the root of the project folder.

Here are a couple pictures from `Android` and `WindowsPhone` once you have done things correctly:-

[image]
[image]

Comment: Image is till not working I get this error:Unhandled Exception when I pun an image marked as AndroidResource in Drawable folder under resouces :

Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Comment: If you pop your solution over I will take a look in a bit, but it does work as described above.  Details are on my profile.

Comment: Thank you Pete. I have mailed you the source code for your reference. I will implement the changes

Comment: Your solution of putting image in rootfolder works, but is there anyway I can have in folder?

Comment: Your Android project is showing the microphone image so I'm assuming this works now.  You have another exception, however its unrelated to this layout issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102687/discussion-between-arti-and-pete).

Comment: will the listview be responsive using grid?

Answer (score 0):

Your file path "Images/img.png" to the image may be not be correct. This directory says from the current directory of the .cs file, there is a folder called Images at the same level and within Images folder is an image with file name img.png. Please check is this true. If I saw your directory structure I would have a difinitive answer. But this is where I would look first.

The file path should be `"~/Images/img.png"` base on the directory structure you provided

Comment: I have attached a image of the folder structure for your reference. And Also would like to know any specific properties has to set for image file?

Comment: File path should be "~/Images/img.png"

Comment: You may have other issues. Here is a resource https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/